# Is $n_{cr}=\frac{60}{2\pi}\sqrt{g\frac{\Sigma m_iy_i}{\Sigma m_iy_i^2}} =\frac{60}{2\pi}\sqrt{g\frac{\int y_idx}{\int y_i^2dx}}\quad ?$

Tags: classical-mechanics, integration, calculus

I have a question about this formula used to calculate the first critical speed of a drive shaft.

$$
n_{cr}=\frac{60}{2\pi}\sqrt{g\frac{\Sigma m_iy_i}{\Sigma m_iy_i^2}} \tag {1} \quad .$$

It is the most commonly used and can be found as the Rayleigh-Ritz method. Well, my doubt consists in that if instead of using summations, I can use integrals, since I consider that the result would be more precise and also, because I think that this surely was the original form of the formula. The new formula would look like this:

$$
n_{cr}=\frac{60}{2\pi}\sqrt{g\frac{\int y_idx}{\int y_i^2dx}} \tag{2} \quad .
$$

I came to this because when I saw formula 1, it reminded me of Riemann summations, and just to test if it was valid, I programmed both formulas in Matlab to compare the results and, to my amazement, I obtained very similar results to those in the book. I am not very good at mathematics, so I am not sure that formula 2 is an improved equivalent of formula 1, besides I have not seen it that way in any other book related to this topic of critical velocities. On the other hand, the only difference between both formulas, apart from the conversion from summations to integrals, is the variable "m" which in this case represents a mass. As you can see, in formula 2, this variable is no longer considered and I am surprised that in spite of it I obtain practically equal results. Finally, if the use of integrals instead of summations is correct in this case, I would be grateful if you could explain it to me mathematically. Well, that's all, the part below is to explain even more about the calculations I did and the results I obtained, but I think that maybe they are not very necessary for the answer you can give me.

---

**Detailed calculations**

The exercise I used for the comparison of the formulas is the one in the following image and as you can see, the result of the book is 2780 rpm. This result is not very accurate for 2 reasons: 1) The first one is that the displacements used in formula 1, were calculated by means of not so accurate formulas. 2) The second is that they were only calculated for 3 points, so if they had been calculated for more points, I think the result would have been more accurate. That is why my objective was not to obtain a result exactly the same as the one in the book, but a very close one.

[image]

This image represents the displacements of the drive shaft as a set of continuous functions. The one on the right is from the text (it considers a constant diameter shaft) and the one on the left is mine (I consider the real diameters of the shaft). It is difficult and time consuming to express the displacements of an shaft by continuous functions, so they are usually calculated for specific points by simple but not so precise formulas. Anyway, you can see that for this case, the results were very similar (this justifies the similarity between my results and those of the book.).

[image: Results of displacements]

As I mentioned before, I have programmed both formulas in matlab considering the same input parameters. This code corresponds to the first one and as you can see, I just evaluated the displacement functions for certain points of the drive shaft and replaced them in the formula (considering also the mass), obtaining 2763.6395 rpm as final answer.

```
% Code using the formula 1
sm1 = 0;
sm2 = 0;
for i =1:length(R)
    my1 = abs((M(i) * subs(y(i), (N(i+1) + N(i)) / 2)));
    my2 = abs((M(i) * subs(y(i)^2, (N(i+1) + N(i)) / 2)));
    sm1 = my1 + sm1;
    sm2 = my2 + sm2;
end
w = (30 / pi) * sqrt(G * (sm1 / sm2));
disp(['Critical speed: ', num2str(double(w)), ' rpm']) → 2763.6395 rpm
```

The following code corresponds to the second formula, so I only had to integrate each of the displacement functions with respect to its length on the drive shaft (I did not consider the mass at any time), obtaining as final result 2764.4172 rpm.

```
% Code using the formula 2
sm1 = 0;
sm2 = 0;
for i =1:length(R)
    my1 = abs(int(y(i), N(i), N(i + 1)));
    my2 = abs(int(y(i)^2, N(i), N(i + 1)));
    sm1 = my1 + sm1;
    sm2 = my2 + sm2;
end
w = (30 / pi) * sqrt(G * (sm1 / sm2));
disp(['Critical speed: ', num2str(double(w)), ' rpm']) → 2764.4172 rpm
```

As you can see 2763.6395 and 2763.6395 are practically the same, although at the time of calculating the second result, I did not consider the mass of the drive shaft, and this is what I find most strange. On the other hand, both are similar to the result of the book, so they were calculated correctly.